# How to insert multiple rows into a PostreSQL database using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I'm trying to add multiple rows to my database in ReactJS by using

```
let request = new Request('http://localhost:3000/songs', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
```

Here's what the data array looks like

[image]

And in my NodeJS app I'm trying add the objects like this

```
addSong = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
  const { name, link } = request.body;

  pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (name, link) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *', [name, link], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(results.rows);
    response.status(201).send(`Songs added` + request.body.name);
  }
 });
}
```

**index.js**

```
const app = express();
const db = require('./queries');
app.post('/songs', db.addSong)
```

The problem I'm facing is I believe the code in the NodeJS app only can insert one record? How do I make it so that I can add all the objects from the array to make multiple rows? I was told a for loop which sounds right but I don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to save all the objects to the database by using a for loop:

```
const addSong = (request, response) => {
  const id = parseInt(request.params.id)
  const { name, link } = request.body;

for (var i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {
  pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (name, link) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *', [request.body[i].name, request.body[i].link], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log("Rows " + JSON.stringify(results.rows));
  }
 });
 }
}
```

I iterate through each object in my array and insert each object with `[request.body[i].name, request.body[i].link]`.

Answer (score -1):

Query :

```
"INSERT INTO songs (name, link) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *',  [[name1,link1], [name2,link2]];"
```